# Automatically set current dynamic IP address to static - Windows .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to configure multiple machines to automatically set their IP addresses from dynamic to static.

I have a batch file to set the IP address to static like this :

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" source=static ^
addr=192.168.200.200 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.200.1
pause
exit /b 0
```

But I have to manually write the IP address, mask and gateway in the .bat file.

How can I retrieve the current IP address of the machine (as well as the current mask and gateway) and automatically set them to static, without modifying the .bat file every time?

Comment: Doing this in batch is like hitting yourself with hammers for fun; use powershell. I assume you realize that if you convert DHCP-leased addrs to static and anyone ever changes any device on your network -- which in practice always happens, no matter how fervently they promise it won't -- everything will break, but that's out of scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for recommending powershell. What do you imply by "change a device on your network" ? Do you mean replacing the physical machine with another? These machines are meant to be local servers, so if replacement is needed, we anticipate a protocol for reverting to DHCP beforehand. What other "change" were you thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to retrieve the current ip address.

Probably this is easy, if you use always the same name for the interface.

```
    setlocal
    set "interface_name=Ethernet"
    REM *** Convert the output lines from netsh into variables
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('"netsh interface ipv4 show addresses name="%interface_name%""') do (
        REM *** Get rid of leaing spaces and TABS
        for /F %%a in ("%%a") DO for /F %%b in ("%%b") DO (
          set "__%%a=%%b"
        )
    )
    REM *** Show all variables beginning with "__"
    set __
    
    if "%__DHCP%" NEQ "Yes" goto :no_dhcp

    :check_ip_prefix
    set "ip_addr=%__IP-address%"
    if "%ip_addr:192.168.=%" EQU "%ip_addr%" goto :wrong_ip_prefix
    
    netsh interface ipv4 set address name="%interface_name%" source=static ^
addr=%ip_addr% mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=%__default_gateway%
```

Probably you need to change some variable names, because the names are language dependent (and I'm using a German version).